# Cannot access union member in class destructor

Tags: c++

I’m implementing a `QVariant`-like class called `Variant` using an anonymous union:

```
class Variant
{
public:
    // …

    ~Variant();

    // …

private:
    Type _type;
    union
    {
        int      _int;
        uint64_t _uint64;
        float    _float;
        void*    _ptr;
    };
};
```

It segfaults in `Variant::~Variant()` when trying to delete the `Variant::_ptr` member as `String*`:

```
Variant::~Variant()
{
    if (_type == Type::String)
        delete reinterpret_cast<String*>(_ptr);
    else if (_type == Type::Date)
        delete reinterpret_cast<Date*>(_ptr);
    // …
}
```

That is allocated this way:

```
Variant::Variant(const String& str)
  : _type(Type::String),
    _ptr(new String(str))
{}
```

What is curious is that, in GDB, on the destructor stack frame, I cannot access the union members but I can access the `Variant::_type` member.

```
(gdb) frame
#0  0x0000000000527700 in Variant::~Variant (this=0x7fffec0337a0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at Sources/Types/Variant.cpp:85
85                      delete reinterpret_cast<String*>(_ptr);
(gdb) p _ptr
No symbol "_ptr" in current context.
(gdb) p _int
No symbol "_int" in current context.
(gdb) p _float
No symbol "_float" in current context.
(gdb) p _type
$2 = Variant::String
```

It seems the union is already deleted, and thus, it segfautls trying to delete `_ptr` which it cannot access to. But why?

Comment: I suspect that it's an "anonymous union" and symbols issue. What happens if you do `p this->_ptr`?

Comment: Have a look at `Boost.Variant`. That’s a clean, efficient implementation with a proper, type-safe API. Using a type-unsafe variant is generally not a good idea but if you need it, take a look at `Boost.Any` instead which provides a clean, efficient, usable implementation of that.

Comment: Show the copy constructor of the type.

Comment: I can access the member using `this->_ptr` but it still segfaults.

@LucDanton `String` does not have a user-defined copy constructor, the class privately inherits from `std::string`.

Comment: The type in question being your `Variant`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that you didn't implement your own copy constructor and the default one just copies the pointer instead of allocating new memory. Then when copies of the original are destroyed it results in double delete.

But unless this is an exercise just use `boost::variant` or `boost::any` because they're already robust well-developed solutions.

Comment: You were right, I’m not used of data-semantic objects containing allocated objects. That’s fixed now, thanks. I’ll take a look at `boost::variant` but I’m skeptical it will fit my needs.